# How can I log trace information from an Azure Static Website?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-static-website-hosting

I have a JavaScript website deployed into an Azure Storage Account (Static Website) and I would like to log debug information (somewhere). For example, when a user logs in, I would like to track them around the site and print user input/responses.

Think of a Console.log("User exited shopping basket"), except instead of "Console." I want something more permanent in Azure. I have been looking at App Insights but to me this is more suited to tracking page loads and 404 errors etc; not the granularity that I need.
Is there anyway I can call ApplicationInsights.log("User exited shopping basket") from JavaScript to use that existing framework?

Or alternatively, how does one log debug/trace information from a Static Website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Insights will provide what you're after.

[Check out this getting started page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript) for use within JS. Once you have everything set up, you can leverage the [custom events and metrics APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics) to collect the type of event data you showed.

[The Readme on the SDK repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS) also has some good tactical examples of how to use AI in your web site.

Comment: Thank you, this looks exactly what I'm after.